# Target ads to users who have visited my page (outside facebook)

Tags: facebook, ads, facebook-ads-api

I was researching for retargeting ad companies and I visited `xxxx` company at their own website (outside Facebook) and about 30 minutes later when I was checking my facebook account I started seeing ads from that company (which I am sure I have never seen before). Also I am not a "fan" of the company or have liked the page on Facebook so I am pretty sure it has to do with me visiting their URL.

Is it possible to target people who have visited my/any URL outside facebook? Till now I thought the only way of targeting people on Facebook was using their graph data.

Thanks!

Comment: Were you signed in while you were checking the company's website?

Comment: Yes, I was signed to Facebook while I was visiting the company website. There is no doubt facebook tracked me, but I am not aware there is an option to target people in this way

Comment: I'm not too familiar with advertising or how Facebook handles it, but I would guess that the company website had a Facebook tracker on their page that requested cookies from your browser pertaining to your username on Facebook. The script on the company website then sends information to Facebook letting them know you viewed that company page, hence the change in what advertisements you see on your profile page. I'm hesitant to post this as an answer though since I could be wrong.

Comment: Thanks Jason, yes, it looks like thats how they do it, but I am not aware facebook is allowing that type of advertising, there is no hook (of which I am aware) that lets you target specific Facebook users IDs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sounds like [Facebook Exchange](http://www.insidefacebook.com/2012/10/25/facebook-exchange-what-it-is-and-who-to-work-with-to-get-started/).

Comment: Thanks, It looks like that. I will check those companies although its strange they don't open it to every customer.